# Get access to variable inside function

Tags: javascript

I am trying to get access to a varible named `has_photo` inside function inside `Vk.api.call` but to no avail.

I have tried multiple things to make it work, like adding a return function or adding name to the function and then calling it.

My goal is to repeat the API call until user has a photo.

```
VK.Api.call('users.get', {
  user_ids: 99,
  fields: "has_photo",
  v: "5.73"
}, function (r) {
  has_photo = r.response[0].has_photo;
  return has_photo;
  }
);
```

Comment: But what and where is has_photo (the variable) in relation to this code?

Comment: It says has_photo is not defined but when I define it it says undefined. Either way it doesnt hold the response from api outside of the function.

Comment: Here is where I fount the answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6847697/how-to-return-value-from-an-asynchronous-callback-function